# Checking what ESP8266 module that is in use

Tags: esp8266

I have this script where I have connected an ESP-01 to an SSD1306 OLED screen. However, the script I'm using needs adaption for ESP-01 as this module requires the I2C pins to be defined.

So basically I need to add a line that says `Wire.begin(2, 0);` so make the screen work with the ESP-01.

Whoever, I would love to have a check that is wrapped in a `#ifdef` so the code will work out of the box with multiple ESP modules without changing the source code.

Is there some way I can check if the module in use is an ESP-01?

Comment: you can check with ifdef which board is selected in Tools menu

Comment: @Juraj As programming the ESP01 requires me to use the Generic 8266 Module option, I guess it's not possible then?

Comment: try the `ARDUINO_BOARD` macro, which is different for wemos and nodemcu and esp01, not sure about others...